# DeezerConnect.setAccessToken() method is missing in latest Deezer Android SDK 0.10.17 Beta

Tags: android, deezer

Today I was about to replace the old stable Deezer Sdk version(v0.10.16) with the latest  SDK (v0.10.17), when I observed that the new Sdk class DeezerConnect.class does not have setAccessToken() method anymore.

This was very useful for me for logging with different users, with different deezer accounts, because I made the AccessToken persistent on the server  for each user, and setting it to DeezerConnect.class when user reentered in the application.

Is there any other way to set the acces token to DeezerConnect?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the setAccessToken is not public anymore in the v0.10.17, it's a mistake. Please note though that the SDK 0.10.17 is still in beta as of today.

Comment: Thank you for this information! I was a little bit worried.
I will check the setAccessToken() availability in the next build release.